# Segundo guard o auth de laravel agregado no me guarda el usuario autenticado

Tags: laravel, autenticación, auth, middleware, guards

tengo este siguiente codigo el cual agrego un guard adicional o custom a mi archivo auth.php en laravel llamado 'students'

```
'defaults' => [
'guard' => 'web',
'passwords' => 'users',],

'guards' => [
'web' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'users',
],
 'student' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'students',
    'remember' => true,
    'expire' => 1440, // Duración en minutos (ejemplo: 1 día)
],],
'providers' => [
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\Models\User::class,
],

 'students' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\Models\Students::class,
],
'passwords' => [
'users' => [
    'provider' => 'users',
    'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
    'expire' => 60,
    'throttle' => 60,
],
 'students' => [
    'provider' => 'students',
    'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
    'expire' => 60,
    'throttle' => 60,
],
```

],

Cuando valido en mi funcion el primer if llamando al auth "web" que es el que esta por defecto en laravel si me realiza la validación en cual busca en el modelo "users", pero cuando no encuentra a ese usuario y pasa al segundo if para validar si el usuario existe en el modelo "Students" lo encuentra pero no guarda el usuario autenticado o sus credenciales

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{

    //Valida que sean enviados data en el request de correo y contraseña en los inputs del login
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required'],
    ]);

    //Verificar si existe el usuario autenticado por Laravel, si no, regresa a la pagina con los mensajes de errores
    if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials, $remember = true))
    {
        //Regresa a la ruta dashboard con los datos del usuario autenticado.
        $user = auth()->user();
        return view('dashboard', ['user' => $user]);
       //return redirect()->route('dashboard',['user' => $user]);

    }
       
    if (Auth::guard('student')->attempt($credentials, $remember = true)) 
    {   
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('dashboard', ['user' => $user]);    
    }

    return back()->with('message', 'Credenciales Incorrectas');
}
```

En el segundo If igualmente tengo la variable $remembe=true; como en el primero deberia guardar dicha autenticación para mandar a la vista los datos del usuario autenticado, pero este no los guarda.

dandome el tipico error en la vista "Attempt to read property "name" on null"

cuando utilizo:

```
<div class="info">
    <a href="#" class="d-block">{{ $user->name }} {{ $user->lastname }}</a>
  </div>
```

Lo que si me he dado cuenta es que si cambio el guard por defecto de laravel que es "web" por el nuevo "student" si me valida los usuarios estudiantes pero no los que estan ubicados en el modelo Users.

y quiero poder implementar ambos auth o guards o quizas varios a la vez.